# Has anyone been able to use the .NET provider model with a winforms app?

Tags: winforms, provider-model

I've seen oodles of examples for ASP.NET, but none for winforms. In other words, using the app.config instead of web.config.  It would be a shame if it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works exactly the same. The base provider model is part of System.Configuration, which abstracts (provider!) whether the application is configured via app.config or web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Client Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx) if you want to use ASP.NET providers in your Windows apps.

If you wish to use the Provider Pattern in a Windows app, this can also be done. I once did this to allow configuration between a real scanner and a fake one (yes I know I could of used an IOC container).

CodeProject probably has several provider tutorials- here is one: [link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/provider_pattern_files.aspx)